# An WorkflowError with wildcards

Tags: error-handling, wildcard, snakemake

I want to use snakemake to QC the fastq file, but it show that :
WorkflowError:

> Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files
>   or a rule without wildcards.

The code I wrote is like this

```
SAMPLE = ["A","B","C"]

rule trimmomatic:
    input:
        "/data/samples/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "/data/samples/{sample}.clean.fastq"
    shell:
        "trimmomatic SE -threads 5 -phred33 -trimlog trim.log {input} {output} LEADING:20 TRAILING:20 MINLEN:16"
```

I'm a novice, if anyone know that, please tell me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do one of the following, but chances are you want to do the latter one.

- Explicitly specifiy output filenames via commandline:

  ```
  snakemake  data/samples/A.clean.fastq
  ```

  This would run rule to create file `data/samples/A.clean.fastq`
- Specify target output files to be created in Snakefile itself using `rule all`. [See here](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) to learn more about adding targets via `rule all`

  ```
  SAMPLE_NAMES = ["A","B", "C"]

  rule all:
      input:
          expand("data/samples/{sample}.clean.fastq", sample=SAMPLE_NAMES)

  rule trimmomatic:
      input:
          "data/samples/{sample}.fastq"
      output:
          "data/samples/{sample}.clean.fastq"
      shell:
          "trimmomatic SE -threads 5 -phred33 -trimlog trim.log {input} {output} LEADING:20 TRAILING:20 MINLEN:16"
  ```

Comment: I have solved the problem with your help ，thank you so much!